# Using Abstract Classes with Header Files in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, header-files

Just recently learned the correct application of inheritance of classes in Java and thought to apply it to some code I'm writing in C++.

The following is a header for an empty Node.cpp:

```
#ifndef Node_h
#define Node_h

#include <string>

using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Class Declarations
class Array;
class Hash;
class Node;
    class BodyNode;
        class RealNode;
            class CharNode;
            class ComboNode;
        class EndNode;
    class HashNode;
    class NodeFollower;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Class Definitions
class Node{
public:
    virtual string toString(int info) = 0;
    };

class BodyNode: public Node{
public:
    };

class RealNode: public BodyNode{
protected:
    Hash *wordHash, *addressHash;
    Array *followers;
    int count;

//Initialization
    RealNode();
    ~RealNode();

//Hashes
    BodyNode getNext(int address);
    NodeFollower getWord(BodyNode *word);
    NodeFollower getAddress(int address);

    string toString(int info);
    };

#endif
```

From this code, I get the following error:

```
Node.h:43:11: error: invalid abstract return type for member function ‘BodyNode RealNode::getNext(int)’
Node.h:28:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘BodyNode’:
Node.h:25:17: note:     virtual std::string Node::toString(int)
```

Looked this up all over google, stackoverflow, and cplusplus, and while I find a lot of answers that surround this concern, I couldn't find the exact answer that I needed to fix it. The cplusplus.com site that I was sourcing from is:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Additionally, a few of the answers I found on stackoverflow indicated that

```
using namespace std;
```

is to be avoided, and it sounds like for good reason, but I can't figure out how to include string. I tried

```
string::string
```

for each declaration, and I tried

```
using namespace std::string;
```

but both were to no avail. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: if you don't want to use the whole namespace you will have to qualify it wherever you use it.  
So it will be std::string variableName;  
  I'd suggest you read what namespaces are :) and how they work !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that BodyNode inherits from regular Node which has a `toString()` **pure-virtual function**.  If it's pure-virtual (the =0) then you MUST provide a definition for it in all derived classes, and you have not.

So, since you have not provided the pure-virtual function definition within `BodyNode`, it is also an abstract class and uninstantiable (an abstract-class has 1 or more pure-virtual methods so it cannot be instantiated).

You also have an issue that `getNext()` returns a `BodyNode` type, and since `BodyNode` is abstract, this isn't possible - you COULD return a pointer to it instead of a by-copy-value, but I think your real problem is that it shouldn't be abstract in the first place.

**Provide a default `toString()` function in BodyNode to fix your problem.**

Comment: Ohhhhh... Thank You! Wow, I never would have gotten that!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use abstract class as a function return type. But you can return pointer or reference to it, like in following declarations:

```
BodyNode* getNext(int address);
BodyNode& getNext(int address);
```

You can declare your string as:

```
#include <string>
...
std::string myString;
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. w00te was able to piece together what I was actually trying to accomplish, but thank you very much as well!

Comment: @Daniel You are welcome. Glad you have found the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since `BodyNode` is also an abstract class, you can not return it from `getNext`. You either have to return a reference or a pointer.

Comment: My goal here is to not have **BodyNode** as an abstract class. I would like **Node** to be abstract, and I would like **BodyNode** to use virtual functions, (which had **toString()** defined, but isn't included here and seemed to have no impact on the error) and I would like **RealNode** to be a "solid" object.

Comment: @DanielP. In that case you have to change `BodyNode` from being an abstract class, by implementing `toString` in that one too.

Answer (score 0):

`BodyNode` is also an abstract class because - Classes derived from the abstract class must implement the pure virtual function or they, too, are abstract classes.

You can not return an object of type `BodyNode`. You can only return a pointer or a reference. Refer this-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8whxhf1.aspx